# HAProxy to CloudFront

Tags: haproxy

I have two components to my application, an API server (which is shared between several versions of the app), and static asset servers for the different distributions (mobile/desktop).  I am using HAproxy to make the API server and the static asset servers behave as though they are on the same domain (to prevent CORS nastiness).  My static asset servers are on CloudFront.  Eventually, the HTML will reference the cloudfront URLs for the assets it depends on (to leverage global distribution).  Temporarily for ease, I'm just having everything go through HAProxy.  I'm having a hard time, however, getting HAProxy to send stuff properly to cloudfront.

My backend definition looks like this:

```
backend music_static
  http-request set-header Host <hash>.cloudfront.net
  option httpclose
  server cloudfront <hash>.cloudfront.net
```

I figured that by setting the Host header value, I would be "spoofing" things correctly on their way to CloudFront.  Obviously, visiting .cloudfront.net behaves exactly as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You probably moved over from this issue, but I see its not answered yet.

One solution to this issue is to enable SNI on CloudFront (this cost money, but worked for me - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html). The above Host header doesnt help, as HTTP Host header is sent after TCP handshake, and to support SNI CloudFront requires host details in TCP handshake.